# CLUEMondo unable to tick boxes

Tags: logistic-regression

I am currently exploring the CLUEMondo model for my master thesis. However, there is a problem in the Logistic Regression Sampling and Parameter selection section, since i cannot tick any of the boxes to perform the logistic regression upon. It seems to still work but the program won't show the ticks, so its more of a guessing game to decide which layers to include...
Does anyone have experienced the same problem, and how can it be solved?